# refresh label text in another form after button click C#

Tags: c#, forms

i have 2 project in 1 solution and each project have 1 form. In form 1 i have label and button, and i want when i click on button it will show in form 2 labeltext in form 1.

my code in form 1:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 layarForm1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1();
layarForm1.Show();
layarForm1.LabelText = no_antrian.Text;
//layarForm1.LabelText = this.Refresh();
```

form2(in other project but in same solutions, and i have reference to form 1):

```
public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ruang_1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ruang_1.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

my code work for first time but when i click button again it will show new form. is there any ways that label text in form 2 will refresh after button click. And i dont want to use dispose form because in form 2 i have video played that will start again if i use dispose() and show()

Comment: You need to check whether the form object already created or not. If yes, just update the label text. The current code always create a new instance of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Two projects = 2 executable you need to use shared memory or named pipes to send the data across from one exe to another, or use winapi such as SendMessage once you get the window handle of the other window and the find the child window handle via EnumChildWindows.

Why not use the two forms in the same project?

Comment: thanks Xela, because project 2 only show data on second monitor. could you show to me how to use winapi sendMessage?

Comment: I can... but I think the preferred way would be to use named pipes to send data from one form to another..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is every time the button is clicked, an instance of the form is created. You need to check whether the form is already open and if not create an instance, show the form and update the label.

If the form is already open, all you need to do is to update the label and set focus on the form.

You can use [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) to iterate through all one forms and check whether the form is in that collection.

Something like

```
foreach (Form frm in WindowsFormsApplication1.OpenForms)  
{  
    if (frm.Name == "MY_FORM_NAME") then
       frm.LabelText = no_antrian.Text;
    else
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 layarForm1 = new       
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1();
        layarForm1.Show();
        layarForm1.LabelText = no_antrian.Text;
    }
}
```